# What is the point of Pure functions in solidity

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I understand why "view" is useful when you create functions in solidity but I don't understand why would someone use pure?

I get that it does not ready or overwrite state variables but why is that useful when coding?

for example:

```
function add (uint _x , uint _y) public pure returns (uint) {
        returns _x + _y;
```

Comment: I think the difference is how they convey the intention of the programmer, using pure adds some restrictions on what you can do within the function, for example you are not allowed to call functions that interact with the state. Other than that, there's technically not much distinction between the two,.. if there is any I'd also like to know

Comment: you have to ask Vitalik :)  the only thing I could think of is preparing the evm to read the state would be an extra heavy load. eventually functions executed on the stack so preparing the stack might be costly

Comment: In general: Pure functions are guaranteed not to have side effects. That makes it easier to review them for safety: a lot of things one might otherwise need to worry about are impossible. Thus, one can try to write a program to have as many pure functions as possible and identify the things that need particularly careful review because they _can't_ fit inside the constraints purity requires.

Comment: That said, "what's the use of X?" questions are often off-topic when X can have several different uses or if when it's most appropriate is open to opinion. Stack Overflow works best for narrow, specific questions with canonical answers; "what's this language feature good for?" is very often both open-ended and opinion-based, and being either of those things makes a question off-topic here.

Comment: thank you all guys for responding I appreciate it.